# Change package name of android app in alpha version

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I want to change the package name of my app before publishing as production version. I started this project and development under test package name, so before production I want to change it to a meaningful one. My app has in-app purchase, google leaderboard as well, so the app is published as alpha version now for testing these features.

I want to know

1. How to change the package name in android studio
2. How to change the package name in google developer console.
3. How to update inapp purchage items and leaderboard

Can these be done? or do I have to create a new listing on google developer console forgetting about current alpha version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. checkout this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/5474351

2 & 3 : you should re-upload your application in google developer console, because your app being identified by the package name.